# What do you call a non-invoked function output?

Tags: javascript, terminology

```
const funcee = () => return 1;

let funcor = funcee;

console.log(funcor)
```

the result is [Function: funcee]

What exactly do you call this? A function definition? 
What exactly is the Javascript Terminology for this?

Comment: It's a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the function reference instead of invoking it.

```js
const funcee = () => {return 1};

let funcor = funcee();

console.log(funcor)
```

Comment: I can't see any function references returned in the OP. And reading the title it seems they know they're not invoking the function.

Answer (score -1):

`funcee` is a function expression.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_expressions

> A function expression is very similar to and has almost the same
>   syntax as a function statement (see function statement for details).
>   The main difference between a function expression and a function
>   statement is the function name, which can be omitted in function
>   expressions to create anonymous functions. A function expression can
>   be used as a IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) which runs
>   as soon as it is defined.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Description

`funcor` I suppose could be defined as a function reference, though this would be an unofficial term.